# In laravel 8, where is defined the @lang directive?

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel, I'm looking for the code that creates the *@lang* directive, to copy the code and create my own version, but I can't find the code. I have found something similar in the trait:

```
Illuminate\View\Compilers\Concerns\CompilesTranslations
```

But I guess it's not the same thing. Where can i found it?

Comment: Actually, I think that's the exact code that does the translations. Are you trying to create your own directive, or your own translator?

Comment: Are you referring to how to do localisation in laravel if so you can look at this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/localization  and  and you can also look at this on how to use @lang https://www.section.io/engineering-education/laravel-language-localization/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@lang` directive is compiled in the `Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler` class.

To be more specific, it's in a function in the `Illuminate\View\Compilers\Concerns\CompilesTranslations` trait.

> ```php
> <?php
>
> namespace Illuminate\View\Compilers;
>
> class BladeCompiler extends Compiler implements CompilerInterface
> {
>     ...
>     use Concerns\CompilesTranslations;
>     ...
> }
> ```

> ```php
> <?php
>
> namespace Illuminate\View\Compilers\Concerns;
>
> trait CompilesTranslations
> {
>     /**
>      * Compile the lang statements into valid PHP.
>      *
>      * @param  string|null  $expression
>      * @return string
>      */
>     protected function compileLang($expression)
>     {
>         if (is_null($expression)) {
>             return '<?php $__env->startTranslation(); ?>';
>         } elseif ($expression[1] === '[') {
>             return "<?php \$__env->startTranslation{$expression}; ?>";
>         }
>
>         return "<?php echo app('translator')->get{$expression}; ?>";
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Compile the end-lang statements into valid PHP.
>      *
>      * @return string
>      */
>     protected function compileEndlang()
>     {
>         return '<?php echo $__env->renderTranslation(); ?>';
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Compile the choice statements into valid PHP.
>      *
>      * @param  string  $expression
>      * @return string
>      */
>     protected function compileChoice($expression)
>     {
>         return "<?php echo app('translator')->choice{$expression}; ?>";
>     }
> }
> ```

The `BladeCompiler` is registered as a singleton in the `Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider` class.

> ```php
> <?php
>
> namespace Illuminate\View;
>
> ...
> use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
> use Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler;
> ...
>
> class ViewServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
> {
>     /**
>      * Register the service provider.
>      *
>      * @return void
>      */
>     public function register()
>     {
>         ...
>         $this->registerBladeCompiler();
>         ...
>     }
>     ...
>     /**
>      * Register the Blade compiler implementation.
>      *
>      * @return void
>      */
>     public function registerBladeCompiler()
>     {
>         $this->app->singleton('blade.compiler', function ($app) {
>             return tap(new BladeCompiler($app['files'], $app['config']['view.compiled']), function ($blade) {
>                 $blade->component('dynamic-component', DynamicComponent::class);
>             });
>         });
>     }
>     ...
> }
> ```

Which is finally added to the provider array in the `config/app.php`.

> ```php
> <?php
>
> return [
>     ...> 
>     'providers' => [
>         ...
>         Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
>         ...
>     ],
>     ...
> ];
> ```